# Smooth lines on ImageView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I currently have a project within Xcode that allows a user to draw upon an ImageView which is working perfectly, my only issue is that the lines that are drawn are not clear and are very blury and rigid. I have tried to implement some ideas ive seen around but they're all in a much older version of swift which i cannot get working.

[Screenshot of the blury lines](https://ibb.co/2hmTHrK)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var toolicon: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!


    var lastPoint = CGPoint.zero
    var swiped = false
    var red:CGFloat = 0.00
    var green:CGFloat = 0.00
    var blue:CGFloat = 0.00
    var alpha:CGFloat = 1
    var lw:CGFloat = 2.5
    var tool:UIImageView!
    var isDrawing = true
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tool = UIImageView()
        tool.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.size.width, y: self.view.bounds.height, width: 75, height: 75)
        tool.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "blank")
        self.view.addSubview(tool)
    }

    @IBAction func eraser(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if (isDrawing) {
            (red,green,blue) = (1,1,1)
            tool.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "eraser2")
            toolicon.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "pen"), for: .normal)
            (lw) = (50)


        } else {
            (red,green,blue) = (0,0,0)
            tool.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "blank")
            toolicon.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "eraser"), for: .normal)
            (lw) = (2.5)
        }

        isDrawing = !isDrawing
    }

    func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
    }

    @IBAction func save(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if let image = imageView.image {
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
            self.imageView.image = nil

            // the alert view
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Thank you, your guestbook entry has been saved. Redirecting you the home page", preferredStyle: .alert)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            // change to desired number of seconds (in this case 5 seconds)
            let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2.5
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when){
                // your code with delay
                alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
            delay(3.0) {
                // do stuff
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "savetocam", sender: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    @IBAction func lineSize(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if sender.tag == 8 {
            (lw) = (1)
        } else if sender.tag == 9 {
            (lw) = (2.5)
        } else if sender.tag == 10 {
            (lw) = (5)
        }
    }


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        swiped = false
        if let touch = touches.first  {
            lastPoint = touch.preciseLocation(in: self.view)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func colorsPicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if sender.tag == 0 {
            (red,green,blue) = (0,0,0)
        } else if sender.tag == 1 {
            (red,green,blue) = (0.25,0.00,0.39)
        } else if sender.tag == 2 {
            (red,green,blue) = (0.65,0.62,0.75)
        } else if sender.tag == 3 {
            (red,green,blue) = (1.00,0.00,0.00)
        } else if sender.tag == 4 {
            (red,green,blue) = (0.49,0.77,0.46)
        } else if sender.tag == 5 {
            (red,green,blue) = (0.0,0.68,0.94)
        } else if sender.tag == 6 {
            (red,green,blue) = (0.96,0.56,0.34)
        } else if sender.tag == 7 {
            (red,green,blue) = (1.00,0.95,0.00)
        }
    }



    @IBAction func reset(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        self.imageView.image = nil
    }


    func drawLines(fromPoint:CGPoint,toPoint:CGPoint) {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
        imageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        context?.move(to:CGPoint(x: fromPoint.x, y: fromPoint.y))
        context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: toPoint.x, y: toPoint.y))

        if(isDrawing){
            context?.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)
        }
        else{
            context?.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.clear)
        }

        tool.center = toPoint
        context?.setLineCap(CGLineCap.round)
        context?.setLineWidth(lw)
        context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha).cgColor)

        context?.strokePath()

        imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        swiped = true
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let currentPoint = touch.preciseLocation(in: self.view)
            drawLines(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: currentPoint)

            lastPoint = currentPoint
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if !swiped {
            drawLines(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: lastPoint)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set your Core Graphics context as follow:

```
func drawLines(fromPoint:CGPoint,toPoint:CGPoint) {

    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, false, 0.0) //SET OPAQUENESS TO FALSE
    imageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    context?.move(to:CGPoint(x: fromPoint.x, y: fromPoint.y))
    context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: toPoint.x, y: toPoint.y))

    if(isDrawing){
        context?.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)
    }
    else{
        context?.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.clear)
    }

    tool.center = toPoint
    context?.setShouldAntialias(true) //IF YOU TURN THIS TO FALSE YOU GET RID OF BLURRING BUT LINES MAY BE A BIT JIGGY
    context?.interpolationQuality = .high //THIS MAKES LINES SMOOTHER
    context?.setLineCap(CGLineCap.round)
    context?.setFlatness(0.5)
    context?.setMiterLimit(0.5) //Play around with this value it should smoothen the angled parts of the signatures.
    context?.setLineWidth(lw)
    context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha).cgColor)
    context?.strokePath()

    imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

also please have a look at other settings which might be also helpful:
[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455178-cgcontextsetshouldantialias)

Comment: Thank you, that would be perfect, i currently have it on github so i can invite you to it, its private at the moment but can make it private if you dont have a github account :)

Comment: My GitHub is verebes1

Comment: thanks :), just shared it to you, apologies if my code is messy, no where near a development level, just trying to throw a few things together for some home projects

Comment: Have a look now. Your project looks fine just play around with the values of miterLimit and that should be ok. When I checked it locally the signatures seems to be quite sharp. I suggest attaching a drawing pencil for the guests to use when signing can be bought on eBay for a few dollars.

Comment: I also added an Enum for your color selection will improve readability but left your old code commented out in case you wish to go back to that version.

Comment: Lastly check the images on a real device. I have just checked and they look great the simulator is somewhat limited.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i really appreciate it, i will check tonight, i plan to run the app on an ipad pro with an apple pencil so it should make it easier, i was thinking of trying to make the app only draw if the pencil has been used but i havent got that far yet

Comment: Glad that I could help. In regards to the Apple pencil I wouldn't use it in case someone would really like to take it with themselves back home  the one's from eBay would work well with your app as it is at the moment.

Comment: So uploaded to my ipad, looks so much smoother on the angles of the writing, do you know how i can make it appear less blury, that was another issue i had you cant really see it that much when the pen is thicker [Screenshot](https://ibb.co/x85KByG)
[Screenshot zoomed](https://ibb.co/Qbb0QNx)

Comment: Is this a screenshot from the simulator or the iPad itself?

Comment: I have added a commit to your code seems much crisper now and also added the code here so anyone trying to find the solution can benefit from it

Comment: thanks, i just found that if i update UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size) to be UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, false, 0.0) which has made it much more clear :D once again thank you so much for your help

Comment: I have updated the answer to it so it can help more people